# Компиляция so на go для cgo

Tags: c++, c, golang

Я пишу на golang. Понадобилось скомпилить всё в *.so. [Сделал](https://medium.com/swlh/build-and-use-go-packages-as-c-libraries-889eb0c19838). Но при вызове из C, вот что получается:

> bash: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

**Пример**

ferret.go:

```
package main

import "C"
import (
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

//export cgoCurrentMillis
func cgoCurrentMillis() C.long {
    return C.long(time.Now().Unix())
}

//export cgoSeed
func cgoSeed(m C.long) {
    rand.Seed(int64(m))
}

//export cgoRandom
func cgoRandom(m C.int) C.int {
    return C.int(rand.Intn(int(m)))
}

func main() {

}
```

Кладу рядом ferret.h:

```
extern long int cgoCurrentMillis();
extern void cgoSeed(long int m);
extern int cgoRandom(int m);
```

Далее делаю так:

> go build -buildmode c-shared -o ferret.so .

Затем создаю файлик:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ferret.h>

int main(void) {
    cgoSeed(cgoCurrentMillis());

    printf("Hello World from C!\n");
//    printf("cgoRandom() -> %d\n", cgoRandom(256));
    return 0;
}
```

Теперь:

> gcc -c -I. -L./ferret.so -o a.out main.c

Дальше:

```
chmod 777 a.out
./a.out
```

На что получаю:

> bash: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Как решить проблему?

---

> gcc -I. -L. -l ferret -o a.out main.c

Получаю

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibferret.so
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: опция -c у gcc запускает компиляцию в объектный файл, а не в исполняемый. Собственно вся часть вопроса, посвященная go совершенно бесполезна и не относится к проблеме.

Comment: @user7860670 добавил пример

Comment: Ну так правильно, файл вы создаете почему-то с названием ferret.so.